# factorize columns of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I got a piece of code from internet to factorize categorical columns of a pandas data frame, but I am having difficulty in understanding it since I am new to python.

Can somebody please explain the following piece of code line by line.

`train` and `test` are pandas data frames with same columns in order.

```
for (train_name, train_series), (test_name, test_series) in zip(train.iteritems(),test.iteritems()):
    if train_series.dtype == 'O':
        #for objects: factorize
        train[train_name], tmp_indexer = pd.factorize(train[train_name])
        test[test_name] = tmp_indexer.get_indexer(test[test_name])
```

I am particularly interested in line `test[test_name] = tmp_indexer.get_indexer(test[test_name])`

And also please explain, what exactly does pd.factorize does? Does it convert characters say, "A", "AA", "AAA" into different numerical factors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First line**: `iteritems` iterates over the columns of a dataframe and returns `(column_name, actual_column)` pairs. By `zip`ping and destructuring in the `for` line, you end up with:

- `train_name`: name of current column in `train` dataframe;
- `test_name`: name of corresponding column in `test` dataframe;
- `train_series` and `test_series`: actual columns (as pandas Series).

**Second line**: this checks if the column is of type `Object`, essentially meaning that it contains strings and is a categorical column.

**Third line**: [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#factorizing-values) will return, in *second* position, the list of unique values (or categorical labels) in the provided column, and, in *first* position, the indices that would let you recreate the original column from the unique values. In other words:

```
labels, uniques = pd.factorize(column)
for i in range(len(column)):
    print(column[i] == uniques[labels[i]])  # True
```

Continuing with destructuring assignments, the current `train` column `train[train_name]` will be replaced by its index-based representation, while `tmp_indexer` will contains the unique values in the original `train[train_name]`.

**Fourth line**: `get_indexer` will return the indices where the values in `test[test_name]` are to be found in `tmp_indexer`. As a result, the current `test` column is replaced by a list of indices in the exact same way the corresponding `train` column was in the line above.

**End result**: both columns in `train` and `test` have gone from a series of strings (categorical values) to a series of numerical index values, both indexed on the same (temporary) object.

Comment: is `zip` function to iterate over two things simultaneously? Can it be used to iterate over any `x` things simultaneously?

Comment: Yes: zip(["a", "b"], [1, 2]) = [("a", 1), ("b", 2)] for instance.

Comment: Like a zipper it zips two lists together.

Comment: It might be nice to include the entire script in addition to the description?